# How can I pop a dialog with a disappearing calling widget?

Tags: flutter

I have a dropdown with an 'Add' link that does a `Navigator.push` to a form for creating a new dropdown element, and that's all working for the standard case.

However, the dropdown has items related to a connected Bluetooth peripheral, and sometimes that peripheral disconnects, so its dropdown closes, while the form is showing, and, in that case, trying to show an error dialog from that form gives me the error:

```
I/flutter (20507): ⚠️ Unhandled Dart error: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 4532 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.
I/flutter (20507): ----------------FIREBASE CRASHLYTICS----------------
I/flutter (20507): 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 4532 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.
I/flutter (20507): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:51:61)
I/flutter (20507): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:5)
I/flutter (20507): #2      NavigatorState._pushEntry (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4532:12)
I/flutter (20507): #3      NavigatorState.push (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4489:5)
I/flutter (20507): #4      showDialog (package:flutter/src/material/dialog.dart:1297:65)
I/flutter (20507): #5      confirm (package:survey/utilities/widgets/dialog.dart:52:20)
I/flutter (20507): #6      _NtripFormState.handleFailedConnection (package:survey/views/ntrip/form.dart:478:18)
I/flutter (20507): #7      _NtripFormState._testConnection (package:survey/views/ntrip/form.dart:467:20)
I/flutter (20507): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (20507): #8      _NtripFormState.testConnection (package:survey/views/ntrip/form.dart:425:12)
I/flutter (20507): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (20507): #9      _NtripFormState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:survey/views/ntrip/form.dart:212:54)
I/flutter (20507): <asynchronous suspension>
```

The `'!_debugLocked': is not true.` error blocks doing a `Navigator.pop` while another `Navigator.pop` is in progress. The `_debugLocked` variable is private, and because this is an assertion it only throws while running in debug mode, so I can't check that variable or catch the error in non-debug code.

I also tried wrapping my `Navigator.pop` calls within `Navigator.canPop` tests, but that doesn't seem to handle a pop within a pop.

Is there some way to detect this state, instead of having to keep track of what's going on in a calling context?

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this issue by `Navigator.pop`ping the dropdown before `Navigator.push`ing the form; the dropdown isn't available to get auto-popped, so the issue is avoided.